# Why my getline() does not read empty lines of a file?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing a function to read a file and display every lines except the empty line. However, when I tried to avoid an empty line, the display still includes every empty line. What's wrong with my code?

```
ifstream rfile;
int lineNum{};

rfile.open(inputFilePath);
for (string line; getline(rfile, line);) {
    lineNum++;
    if (line.empty())
        cerr << "Line " << lineNum << " is empty." << '\n';
    else
        cout << lineNum << ": " << line << '\n';
}
```

The input file contains:

```
10* 8
44 - 88
12 + 132
70 / 7
```

There are 3 new lines. But my output is:

```
1: 
2: 
3: 10* 8
4: 44 - 88
5: 12 + 132
6: 70 / 7
7:
```

Why the new lines are still showing?

I just changed `cout << lineNum << ": " << line << '\n'; into cout << lineNum << ": " << line << ":" << line.length() << '\n';` as @prehistoricpenguin said.
Then the output became:

```
:1
:1
:6
:8
:9
:7
:1
```

Also, I turned on "show whitesapce". In my input file it does not show a spot or whitespace. Yet when running program, the spot(whitespace) shows.

Comment: Does the input file contain `\r\n` line endings?

Comment: @Elijay the file does not contain \r\n. I just add new lines by tapping "enter" to test the function.

Comment: Change this line `cout << lineNum << ": " << line << '\n';` into `cout << lineNum << ": " << line << ":" << line.length() << '\n';`, then you can see the length

Comment: This may be caused by some cross-platform problems, say you create the input file Windows, but your program runs on Linux.

Comment: Try turning on `Show whitespace` in your editor of choice and see if the lines are actually blank.

Comment: Change `cerr` to `cout` and see if that makes a difference. The `cerr` may be going to a different place,

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin Hi, I changed it, and my "empty line" shows 1...... However, I check the file and the empty line is empty.

Comment: All of the lines in your environment have one extra character, so Remy's conclusion must be right.

Answer (score 2):

Your results are consistent with a text file that uses CRLF-style (`\r\n`, `0x0D 0x0A`) line breaks, but your code is using a `std::getline()` implementation that only recognizes LF-style (`\n`, `0x0A`) line breaks, thus leaving `\r` in the output string. That is why the `length()` of each `line` is 1 more character than you are expecting.

You will need to detect and truncate off that extra `\r` character after each `std::getline()` call, eg:

```cpp
ifstream rfile;
int lineNum{};

rfile.open(inputFilePath);
for (string line; getline(rfile, line);) {
    lineNum++;
    if ((!line.empty()) && (line.back() == '\r'))
        line.resize(line.size()-1);
    if (line.empty())
        cerr << "Line " << lineNum << " is empty." << '\n';
    else
        cout << lineNum << ": " << line << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Wow, I dont know there is '\r'！ Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

This works in MSVC with the output:

```
Line 1 is empty.
Line 2 is empty.
3: 10* 8
4: 44 - 88
5: 12 + 132
6: 70 / 7
Line 7 is empty.
```

Comment: Yeah, I am using Clion, but the got a different answer....